# Compiling library with ant script

Tags: java, ant, jar, import, compilation

I created package (project) `Point`, which contains classes `Square`, `Rectangle`, `Point`, `Circle` and `Line`. They are simple classes with constructors for creating said objects.
From main in Point, you call them like this:

```
Point p1 = new Point(0,3);
```

I should write a program, that asks user to select which object he wants to create and set its geometry and i can only use my Point package as a library.

1) create the `simple-graphics.jar` library.
I removed main method in my `Point` package and managed to produce `simple-graphics.jar` executable .jar file from my `Point` package.

2) I am asked to create some ant script that compiles this library from its source files and generates .jar file, however, i have no clue how to do that and if i havent already done it in 1), tutorials on ant scripts are not very clear to me. I guess im supposed to do it both ways, by selecting produce .jar option in NetBeans and by having somewhere this ant script.

3) I should be able to run .jar file generated by 2) by using `java -jar simple-graphics.jar` How do i do that in NetBeans, or should i use cmd? Im on W7.

EDIT:
Thank you for the script, as a look at it i definitely wouldnt be able to write all of that.

How do i use this library in my program? SOLVED - like this:

```
package simpleapp;

import point;

public class SimpleApp{



  public static void main(String [] args){


     //Please press 1 to create Point
     //Please specify x and y axis:
     //i will select the type of object and create it
     //Object o = new whichObject(1)(x,y); 

  }
}
```

Point class in package Point, other classes are very similar:

```
package point;

public class Point{

 double x;
 double y;

 public Point(double a, double b){
  x = a;
  y = b;
 }

 public Point(){
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
 }

 public double distance(Point p){
   return Math.sqrt((p.x - x) * (p.x - x) + (p.y - y) * (p.y-y));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic Ant script (`build.xml`) to compile your Java files to class files and pack them into a JAR file assuming your Java source files are in subdirectory `src`. Be aware that this is only a starting point.

```
<project name="Point-Library" default="build">

  <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
  <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
  <property name="jar.name" value="simple-graphics.jar" />

  <target name="build" depends="prepare, compile, jar" />

  <target name="prepare" description="Creates the build folder">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
  </target>

  <target name="compile" description="Compiles the Java source files">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" />
  </target>

  <target name="jar" description="Packs the compiled Java classes into a JAR file">
    <jar basedir="${build.dir}" destfile="${jar.name}" />
  </target>

</project>
```

But you should first read the [offical Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) to understand the concepts.

To use the resulting JAR file you have to add it to your classpath (which you did already).
Then you can import the package `point`.

```
package simpleapp;

import point; // <---

public class SimpleApp{



  public static void main(String [] args){


     //Please press 1 to create Point
     //Please specify x and y axis:
     //i will select the type of object and create it
     //Object o = new whichObject(1)(x,y); 

  }
}
```

It makes no difference for your client code which uses the `point` classes whether their source code is part of your project or you import only the JAR file containing the `point` class files.

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver! I successfully managed to complete my program and will study and scripts over holidays as im gonna need them in the future anyway.